# how to send several argumetns as input to WorkManager? or how to create constructor? or how to pass object as input?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I need to pass several arguments as input for my WorkManager, but don't know how. Also, I want to pass Repository.

```
    val data = workDataOf("cabinId" to task.cabinId)
     val data2 = workDataOf("repository" to repository)
     val uploadWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<WManager>()
         .setInputData(data)
         .setInputData(data2)
         .build()


class WManager(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(appContext, workerParams) {
override fun doWork(): Result {
    val input = inputData.getInt("cabinId", 99)
    val input2 = inputData("repository")
    return Result.success(outputData)
}}
```

I tried to implement interface serializable for Repository but it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing the right thing. You can pass in multiple key value pairs to `workDataOf`.

So something like:

```
val data = workDataOf("cabinId" to task.cabinId, "repository" to repository)
val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<WManager>()
    .setInputData(data)
    .build()

WorkManager.getContext(context).enqueue(request)
```

This is assuming that `repository` is a serializable type. If not, you will need to do dependency injection.

Comment: my repository is implementing serializable type. but it throws invalid type exeption